# How to tell if all value of object is present in another object

Tags: javascript, object

I want to `doSomething` if all the value of object is present in another object

```
  const object1 = { letter: 'a', number: 1 };
  const object2 = { letter: 'b', number: 2 };
  const object3 = { letter: 'a', number: 1, address: 'not in object4' }
  const object4 = { letter: 'a', number: 1, address: 'different address', section: 'abc' }

  if (isPresent(object1, object4)) doSomething;
```

If I replace the `object1` with `object2` or `object3` in `isPresent` first argumet, it should return false because object4 doesn't have their values, and return true if all the value on argument1 is present on argument2 like on the sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get all entries and check against the other object.

```js
const
    isPresent = (a, b) => Object.entries(a).every(([k, v]) => k in b && v === b[k]),
    object1 = { letter: 'a', number: 1 },
    object2 = { letter: 'b', number: 2 },
    object3 = { letter: 'a', number: 1, address: 'not in object4' },
    object4 = { letter: 'a', number: 1, address: 'different address', section: 'abc' };

console.log(isPresent(object1, object4)); //  true
console.log(isPresent(object2, object4)); // false
console.log(isPresent(object3, object4)); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
  
  
const object1 = { letter: 'a', number: 1 };
const object2 = { letter: 'b', number: 2 };
const object3 = { letter: 'a', number: 1, address: 'not in object4' }
const object4 = { letter: 'a', number: 1, address: 'different address', section: 'abc' }

function isPresent(v1, v2) {
  v2 = JSON.stringify(v2);
  v1 = JSON.stringify(v1).slice(1, -1);
  return v2.includes(v1);
}

console.log(isPresent(object1, object4)); //  true
console.log(isPresent(object2, object4)); // false
console.log(isPresent(object3, object4)); // false
```